# C++ issue with operator overloading with regard to addition

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This is my main function:

```
 int main(){
     Complex c1(1.0, 5.0);
     Complex c2(3.0,-2.0);
     Complex c3(1.0, 2.0);
     cout << "c1 + c2 + c3 = "
         << c1 + c2 + c3 << endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

This is the function I use to add up the required numbers

```
Complex& operator+(const Complex & x, const Complex & y){
    Complex c;
    c.a = x.a + y.a;
    c.b = x.b + y.b;

    return c;

}
```

`a` and `b` are private double variables in my class.

On running my program, I seem to get  the output as 1+2i ie(c3) and it only seems to work properly when I add only 2 objects. Is there any way I can tweak my existing code to allow it to work for up-to n terms?

Comment: s/`Complex& operator+(const Complex & x, const Complex & y)`/`Complex operator+(const Complex & x, const Complex & y)`

Comment: You should return by value, not by reference, you are making a new object. As written you are returning a dangling reference

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise @CoryKramer

Comment: Returning a reference to a local variable causes UB.

Answer (score 3):

Your `operator +` returns a reference to the local variable `c`, which gets destroyed after it is done. Any further use of the result leads to *undefined behavior*.
You need to return a *value*, so it gets copied (or a `rvalue`), but not a *reference*:

`Complex operator+(const Complex & x, const Complex & y)
 {...}`